# Connect oracle to nodejs

Tags: oracle, node.js

i want to connect oracle database 11gR2 to node.js , when i want to install db-oracle package the error occured :

```
npm install db-oracle 
sh: node-wf command not found
```

what i am doing ?

Comment: 1) Which version of node are you using?
2) Which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: the version of node js is 0.10.4 and the version of linux is Cntos 5.9

Comment: Adding a comment because this is a top hit:  the module to connect to Oracle database is `oracledb` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb  It will connect to Oracle DB 9.2 or later, depending which Oracle client libraries it uses.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few pointers:

https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle/issues/53

> Node.js does not support node-waf anymore and therefore this project
>   needs to be update. To install this anyways, 1)Install a lower version
>   of node.js. I noticed this project has not been updated ina about a
>   years so I selected node.js v0.6.4 which came out a year ago. 2)
>   re-run installation 3) now that you have the package installed you may
>   upgrade node.js (cross your fingers that it works or you might have to
>   go back down to a lower version. You'll run into problems if you try
>   to reinstall db-oracle).

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/issues/98) gives a clue. node-waf is replaced by node-gyp. You should follow [this comment](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/issues/98#issuecomment-15124820).